# Retopologizing this mess?

Tags: vertices, sculpting, topology, dynamic-topology

I sculpted this based on my beginner knowledge (forsaking any complex sculpting knowledge that might discourage and keep me from getting to the end), but now I want to paint and pose the character and I have a feeling this topology is going to be difficult to work with. Where do I start?

[image: Solid View]

[image: Topology View]

Comment: My initial thoughts are to merge verts by distance, which completely destroys details but I have the detailed copy in another layer and I've seen sculptors bake detail to a mesh in another layer. However, I imagine it would just reapply the horrendous topology from the detailed mesh, but idk.

Comment: Looks like this is the tutorial I'll be going off of. Had a feeling it would be a long and tedious process. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuQzPDs99yM

Comment: Hey, curious, did you use multiresolution or dynamic topology?

Comment: You can use the sculpt cleanup tool (looks like a snowflake), but this will lose some  of the finer detail but it works well.  You would need to set it to a fixed size rather than dynamic.  For full remeshing have a look at https://github.com/wjakob/instant-meshes

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth it to try and install the new experimental blender 2.81 version and use it’s “voxer remeshing” feature. I don’t think it would fix everything instantly but it could give you a start. Keep in mind that it’s still experimental though so it might do what they intend it to do in the long run.

Comment: Yeah, that feature could be cool.

Answer (score 0):

Heres one way of doing it, but It envolves recreating the topology.

Set the snapping mode to face.
create a new mesh, and delete all except one vertice.
press **g** and move the vertice, the vertice will automatically snap to your character mesh!
now, extrude the vertice to create edges and faces, (using the poly to poly method of modeling) and whenever you extrude or move the vertice, it will snap to the mesh.

I realize this is time consuming, and I suggest you plan your topology flow with the grease pencil, setting the stroke placement to **surface.**

With your current mesh, I don't see any fixing it, I think this is the only way to get a mesh suitable for rigging.

hope this helps, and please comment if you need more detail.

P.S, I like your model, and It's *really* good for a beginner!  I'm a beginner at sculpting too, and I'm not sure I could create that model.